# Using IO.File Class to read a file that is in use

Tags: vb.net

I am working on improving an old class and I am stuck here.

There is a method like this which works.

```
Private Database_Bytes As Byte()
Private Base as String = 'Path of Some database file.
Sub New() 
    If File.Exists(Base) Then
        FileOpen(1, Base, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Shared)
        Dim asi As String = Space(LOF(1))
        FileGet(1, asi)
        FileClose(1)
        Database_Bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(asi)
    End If
    'Operations
End Sub
```

As FileOpen is old and IO Class offers better performance, I am trying to change it to below method but. I get an IOException if the file is in use by another process.

```
Private Database_Bytes As Byte()
Private Base as String = 'Path of Some database file.
Sub New() 
    If File.Exists(Base) Then
        Database_Bytes = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Base)
    End If
    'Operations
End Sub
```

How can I avoid the IOException if the file is in use?

Comment: What error did you encounter?

Comment: While debugging now, I found out that the method is not working because of an IOException; The process cannot access the file (Base) because it is being used by another process. Is there an equivalent to OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Shared overloads in IO.File class?

Comment: I see, then there isn't any issue actually... :)

Comment: Yes. Is there an equivalent to OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Shared overloads in IO.File class? I think that might be the solution to my problem.

Comment: `IO.File.OpenRead` is what you may want to replace `OpenAccess.Read`. `ReadAllBytes` itself is already reading the file as binary, thus there shouldn't be any issue. For more complex way, I think you could look at `IO.File.SetAccessControl` and its `Get` counterpart. As for `OpenShare.Shared` I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have found out, File.ReadAllBytes does not allow you to read a file that is in use. However, you can do that with FileStream.Read.

```
Private Database_Bytes As Byte()
Private Base as String = "Path of Some database file."

Sub New() 
    If File.Exists(Base) Then
        Using fs As New FileStream(Base, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
            ReDim Database_Bytes(CInt(fs.Length) - 1)
            fs.Read(Database_Bytes, 0, Database_Bytes.Length)
        End Using
    End If

    'Operations

End Sub
```

The code above assumes that you have `Imports System.IO` (which seems to be the case based on the code you posted). Otherwise, `File.Exists`, `FileStream`, etc. would need to be qualified (e.g. `IO.File.Exists`, etc.).